# "getElementsByClassName" in IHTMLDocument3

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my BHO (COM DLL), I have code to get the elements by 'id' and 'name' using IHTMLDocument3's `getElementById` and `getElementsByName` api's. I need to get the elements by `class name`. But I dint find any `getElementsByClassName` api with IHTMLDocument3.
I need to get the elements by 'class'.

How can I get the collection elements of 'class' using IHTMLDocument3?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the collection elements of 'class' using IHTMLDocument3?

Manually iterating over the DOM and examining element properties.

However there is a [`getElementsByClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as part of [`IHTMLDocument7`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but this requires a later version of IE to be installed (IE * if I recall correctly). If you have a sufficient version of IE, then you can `QueryInterface` for `IHTMLDocument7` given an interface pointer to an earlier version.

Comment: Manual iteration over the DOM may be a time consuming process. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @santhosh If you have a new enough version of IE installed, then see the second half of my answer.